# Have I somehow altered ctype.h?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

#define HASH_SIZE 5

// prototype
int hash(char *word);

// counter
int counter;

// node
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
} node;

// hash table
struct node *hashtable[HASH_SIZE];



/*
 * Returns true if word is in dictionary else false.
 */

bool
check(const char *word)
{
    //make a writable word (palabra)
    int len = strlen(word);
    char palabra[len + 1];
    //int i;

    // make la palabra all lowercase letters
    for ( int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(palabra[i]) || palabra[i] == '\'')
            palabra[i] = tolower(word[i]);
    }

    //palabra[i] = (char) "\0";

    // hash the word
    int value = hash(palabra);

    // let's look at the first node in the bucket
    struct node *n;
    if (hashtable[value] == NULL)
        return false;
    else
        n = hashtable[value];

    // iterate through the bucket to see if the word is there
    while (strcmp(palabra, n->word) != 0 && n->next != NULL)
    {
        n = n->next;
    }


    // if the word is found, print true, else false
    if ( strcmp(palabra, n->word) ==0 )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}


/*
 * Loads dictionary into memory.  Returns true if successful else false.
 */

bool
load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // open the dictionary
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if(dict == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", dictionary);
        return false;
    }

    // set all values in the hash table to null
    for(int i = 0; i < HASH_SIZE; i++)
    {
        hashtable[i] = NULL;
    }

    // set the counter to 0
    counter = 0;

    // iterate through the words in the dictionary
    while (!feof(dict))
    {
        //declare a node
        node *n = malloc( sizeof(node) );

        // copy the word into the node
        fscanf(dict, "%s", n->word);

        // hash the word, baby!
        int hash_value = hash(n->word);

        // start saving addresses to the hashtable
        n->next = hashtable[hash_value];
        hashtable[hash_value] = n;

        // that's one more!
        counter++;
    }

    // testing
    printf("Starting the test.\n");
    for ( int i = 0; i < HASH_SIZE; i++)
    {
        struct node *q = hashtable[i];
        while (q != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s\n", q->word);
            q = q->next;
        }
    }
    printf("Ending the test.\n");

    fclose(dict);

    return true;
}


/*
 * Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded.
 */

unsigned int
size(void)
{
    return counter;
}


/*
 * Unloads dictionary from memory.  Returns true if successful else false.
 */

bool
unload(void)
{
    // TODO
    return false;
}


/*
 * Returns a hash value for a word.
 */

int
hash(char *word)
{
    // hash value and length of word
    int value = 0;
    int len = strlen(word);

    // iterate through letters, adding ASCII values
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        int letter = (int) word[i];
        value += letter;
    }

    // make sure the value is less than 100 & return
    value = value%HASH_SIZE;
    return value;
}
```

When I run my code, I receive this error message:

In file included from /usr/include/ctype.h:28:0,
                 from speller.c:10:
/usr/include/bits/types.h:31:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'typedef'

Does this mean that I have somehow managed to alter the ctype.h library?  If so, how do I fix it?

Comment: Have you looked at ctype.h, on/around line 28?  Do you see anything wrong there?

Comment: Hmm... I will look up how to open it on ctype.h and let you know...

Comment: Is this the exact code you used (it says `speller.c:10`, but `ctype.h` looks like it's on line 5)? I've had this type of error when I forget a semi-colon or something right before an include.

Comment: ctype.h, line 28:  #include <bits/types.h>

Comment: types.h, line 31:  typedef unsigned char __u_char;

Comment: Aha!  Gordon, you solved it!  I found some stray characters typed just above the #include <ctype.h> that were causing the problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha! Gordon, you solved it! I found some stray characters typed just above the #include  that were causing the problem. Thanks!

Comment: There are no stray characters above. When posting code in a question, please please PLEASE post the **actual code that you used**.